# Find the first column of $M = (A-x_kI)(A-x_{k-1}I)...(A-x_1I)$ using a sequence of GAXPY’s operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A \in \mathbb R^{nxn}$ and $x \in \mathbb R^k$.
> Find the first column of $M = (A-x_kI)(A-x_{k-1}I)...(A-x_1I)$ using a sequence of GAXPY’s operations.

I know that GAXPY (general $A$ $x$ plus $y$): $z = Ax - y$, where $A$ is an $mxn$ matrix, $x$ is a vector of length $n$, and $y$ is a vector of length $m$, and the resulting vector $z$ is of length $m$, but how to use this to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any $m \times n$ matrix $M$, the first column of $M$ is equal to $M e_1$, where $e_1 \in \Bbb R^n$ is the standard basis vector $e_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$.

Try to do this for small $k$ ($k=1,2,3$) and see if you find a general pattern.

---

Here is the answer I would give: define $y_0 = e_1 \in \Bbb R^n$, and define
$$
y_i = (A - x_i I)y_{i-1} \quad \text{for }i = 1,2,\dots,k.
$$
The first column of $M$ is $y_k$. By the recursive description above, we see that $y_k$ is the result of $k$ successive GAXPY operations.

Comment: I guess I understood where you're getting me at, but the idea is still unclear for me. I guess you want me to write $A$ as something related to the bases vectors?

Comment: @JOJO Let me ask this: if you had to give an answer for this question specifically for $k=2$, what would you write?

Comment: I would write $(A-x_2I)(A-x_1I)$

Comment: @JOJO In what way is that a "sequence of GAXPY operations"? In what way is the output of what you wrote the column vector that we want?

Comment: It's like instead of having a vector "$x$" multiplying $I$, I have an entry of $x$, and instead of adding a vector $y$, I'm adding a matrix $A$

Comment: @JOJO I think the first step is for you to figure out what format makes sense for this answer. I don't think that $(A - x_2 I)(A - x_1 I)$ can reasonably be interpreted as "a sequence of GAXPY operations" that produces the first column of this product. That said, I don't know what the textbook/professor who asked this question is looking for.

Comment: That's the point.. I tried for $k = 2$, and for $A$ a $2$ by $2$ matrix, so I got that the first column of $(A-x_2I)(A-x_1I)$ is $(a_{1,1} - x_1)(a_{1,1} - x_2) + a_{2,1} a_{1,2}, a_{2,1}(a_{1,1} - x_2) + a_{2,1}(a_{2,2} - x_1)$ . Is it correct? And if yes, how do I generalize this for any square matrix and any vector of length $k$?

Comment: @JOJO That is not "the point." In any case, I've written what I would give as an answer